# why is it saying I cannot set property fontSize because something is undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror

I recently did a 5 day bootcamp and am trying to teach myself more before I start the full course. I'm trying to use the same "mouseover" function to increase fontSize as I used in the bootcamp but it says it cannot set the property fontSize of undifined. I believe I set the Id of what I want to change and have specified how much I want to change it by...

Honestly I'm very new to this, just trying to get over my first Javascript hurdle.

```js
function thingHover() {
  document.getElementById('Thing').firstChild.style.fontSize = '300%';
}

function thingNormal() {
  document.getElementById('Thing').firstChild.style.fontSize = '100%';
}
```

```html
<p id='Thing' onmouseover="thingHover()" onmouseout="thingNormal"> Dunno what I'm gonna do to this text yet, maybe add some JS? </p>
```

In the boot camp we applied this to an icon instead of text. the icon appeared to hover above its original position slightly larger. I didn't want to just copy paste the icon code in though just because my code for the text didn't work.

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element and the `p` tag does not have any children, so `firstChild` returns `undefined`

Comment: Did you compare the difference between the icon code and your text code?

Comment: As @shrys hinted: Remove the `.firstChild`, as your `<p>` tags don't have children.

Comment: @shrys No, `firstChild` returns a Text-node. But the result is the same as Text-nodes have no style. Only Element-nodes have style.

Comment: @Thomas you're right, my bad

Comment: Whenever you get an error like `cannot set property B because A is undefined` then your code has `A.B` in it somewhere and `A` is undefined. In this case you're using `.firstChild` to grab the text node, and `.style` to get the style, but that yields `undefined` because text nodes don't have a style property.

Comment: Also, if you went to a coding bootcamp that taught to use inline event listener attributes and `firstElementChild.firstElementChild` you should probably ask your money back.

Comment: Free bootcamp ;)

Comment: It should also be noted that `#Thing:hover { font-size: 300% }` does the same thing.

Comment: if I may give you one more hint:
firtChild returns a textnode. In this case you want to access the element. You would get access to the first element with children[0]. So document.getElementById("myElement").children[0].styles();

Comment: Thanks again everyone! I know it's a super basic mistake I made as I'm just starting out but I very much appreciate you taking the time to help and even go beyond and give me extra pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is typo error in  below code, add function bracket when it call

```js
function thingHover() {
           document.getElementById('Thing').style.fontSize='300%'; //remove firstChild
         }
         function thingNormal() {
           document.getElementById('Thing').style.fontSize='100%'; //remove firstChild
         }
           </script>
```

```html
<p id='Thing' onmouseover="thingHover()" onmouseout="thingNormal()"> Dunno what I'm gonna do to this text yet, maybe add some JS? </p> <!--add  space between two attributes and add () on onmouseout-->
```

Comment: Wow you guys are quick! thank you so much! on the original it was firstElementChild.firstElementChild. but I totally see how that works now.

Comment: if it is helpful then accept and vote it @Matt.Mutt

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any child elements, thus no First child:

I made some minor edits, and here is a working snippet.

```js
  function thingHover() {
   var thing = document.getElementById('Thing');
   thing.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '300%';
  }
  function thingNormal() {
  var thing = document.getElementById('Thing');
    thing.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '100%';
  }
```

```html
<script>

</script>
<div id='Thing'onmouseover="thingHover()" onmouseout="thingNormal()">
<p style='fontSize:100%;'>Dunno what I'm gonna do to this text yet, maybe add some JS?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
     function thingHover(size) {
        let hov = document.getElementById('Thing');
        hov.style.fontSize = size+'%';
    }

    function thingNormal(size) {
        let normal = document.getElementById('Thing');
        normal.style.fontSize = size+'%';
    }
```

```html
<p id='Thing' onmouseover="thingHover(300)" onmouseout="thingNormal(100)"> Dunno what I'm gonna do to this text yet, maybe
    add some JS?</p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).